# How to specify which java version to use with sbt 0.12.4?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-0.12

How to specify which java version to use with sbt 0.12.4?
I have java 7 and java 8 installed. Since sbt 0.12.4 does not support java 8 but tries to use it by default, I have to specify java version explicitly for sbt. I want to keep using java 8 as a default version of java for other things.

Comment: have you tried starting SBT with https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras ? It allows you to set the java_home folder as an argument.

Comment: It appears that the java home can be supplied to the original sbt. See comments of the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way that works well for me is, using the sbt script from [sbt-extras](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras) and add to the root of the project a file called `.sbtopts` with:

```
-java-home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home
```

using whatever version of Java 7 you want to use. Make sure that those are on separate.

Comment: Created .sbtopts manually and added -java-home <path> parameter and it solved the problem. Thanks! How sbt-extras can be useful here?

Comment: It has a bunch of interesting and useful flags, have a look at `sbt -help`

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using the sbt script from [sbt-extras](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras) you could use [jEnv](http://www.jenv.be/).

After configuring jEnv, from the root of the project run `jenv local 1.7`, which will create a file called `.java-version` with content "1.7".

Then every time you run `java` (or `javac`, etc) in that project (including from any directory in that project) it will run the 1.6 version, thanks to jEnv's shim mechanisms.