# How to set up sbt on Windows to select a specific JDK (among available JDKs)?

Tags: windows, scala, sbt

Is there a way to tell SBT which (locally) installed JDK to use?

I am quite certain I could change `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` but I'd rather not change those settings since they apply for the whole system (Windows in that case).

I am more looking for a command line parameter of some sort.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701692/setting-up-sbt-to-use-java-7-for-compilation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286058/how-to-specify-which-java-version-to-use-with-sbt-0-12-4.
They might be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar Are you sure that those are the only available options? There is really no command line property out of the box? I cannot be the only developer who has this situation.

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar Addition: To me that mentioned `sbt-extras` look as it was only for Unix/Linux systems but not for Windows.

Comment: You can set env variable like `JAVA_HOME` for your current shell only. You don't have to set it globally in your system. `set JAVA_HOME=c:\<java_installation_folder>` and then run `sbt` from the same shell. When you close the shell the env variable will be gone so you need to do it every time you run sbt in a new shell.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to specify the _JDK_ used to run _SBT_, or the _JDK_ used to run your project and/or tests from within _SBT_?

Comment: @MikeAllen I am not exactly sure. All I want is that sbt uses a specific JDK to compile and run my application.

Comment: OK. By default, _SBT_ uses the same _JDK_ for running your application as it uses itself. My answer below should be OK for you...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're looking to specify a *JDK* for running *SBT* (rather than a *JDK* to use for running your code and/or tests from within *SBT*), you can make use of the `JAVA_HOMES` environment variable, plus a `.java-version` file in your project.

This is described in *SBT*'s `sbt.bat` file (typically installed to `C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin`) as a "poor man's `jenv`", which isn't currently available on *Windows*.

(If you're looking for a similar solution for *Linux* or *MacOS*, you can either use [`jEnv`](http://www.jenv.be/), or specify the *Java* home directory via the `-java-home` *SBT* command line option—which also, sadly, isn't currently implemented on *Windows*.)

The `JAVA_HOMES` environment variable (not to be confused with `JAVA_HOME`) is used by *SBT* to identify a directory that contains one or more *JDK* installations. For example, if you're using [*AdoptOpenJDK*](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)'s *JDK* distributions (recommended on *Windows*, if *Oracle*'s new licensing restrictions are a problem for you), then this would typically be defined as `C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK`.

Let's say that you have two such *JDK* installations in the `JAVA_HOMES` directory: one in a subdirectory named `jdk-8.0.212.03-hotspot`; another in the `jdk-11.0.3.7-hotspot` subdirectory. You can select which *JDK* you want to use, on a project-by-project basis, by creating a file called `.java-version` in the root directory of each *SBT* project. To use the *JDK* in the `jdk-8.0.212.03-hotspot` subdirectory, this file should then contain:

```
jdk-8.0.212.03-hotspot
```

When you run the `sbt` command, if you have `JAVA_HOMES` defined, *SBT* will look for a `.java-version` file in the project's root directory. If it finds it, it creates a local version of `JAVA_HOME` that is defined as `JAVA_HOMES` plus the last line of `.java-version`. It also adds this `JAVA_HOME`'s `bin` directory to the path. (It also creates a `JDK_HOME` process-local environment variable with the same value.)

This should do what you want. Although it's not a command line-based solution, it doesn't adversely affect other users, and allows each *SBT* project to be configured individually. If you do not have permission to create a system-wide environment variable, you should still be able to create a user-specific `JAVA_HOMES` environment variable. Note that when using this solution, the *JDK* that *SBT* uses is then not necessarily the one identified by your system-wide (or user-specific) `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. (If you have not defined `JAVA_HOMES`, then *SBT* will expect you to have defined a valid `JAVA_HOME` variable.)

One word of caution: if you commit `.java-version` to source control, you must ensure that everyone defines a valid `JAVA_HOMES` environment variable, and has a *JDK* with the exact same name installed in that directory.

Comment: Very interesting solution. Didn't find any reference on official docs so thanks for detailed answer.

Comment: This does not appear to be supported _in general_; being unique/specific to windows and sbt.bat.

Comment: @RichardSitze: The question was "How to set up sbt on Windows..." You can use _jenv_ on other platforms; I just explained how to specify the JDK on _Windows_.

Comment: @MikeAllen That was understood, was clear from the title, and implied by your reference to sbt.bat.  It's a very helpful response.  That said, I don't typically see tools providing platform specific solutions (though arguably necessary/helpful for windows), and felt it deserved to be clearly stated.

Comment: This lead me to jenv, which looks to be working! :)

Comment: This helped me find jenv, which worked great on a linux server! :)